# I modified existing student entity through sub generator and then override all and after run gradlew command but I got folling error, what is wrong?

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate, jhipster-registry

2017-12-28 15:40:31.813 ERROR 5060 --- [tapp-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   :
Liquibase could not start correctly, your database is NOT ready: Validation Failed:
     1 change sets check sum
          config/liquibase/changelog/20171228063150_added_entity_Student.xml::20171228063150-1::jhip
ster was: 7:1e76a424cb8d1fd8f33d27559cee9133 but is now: 7:a69d676fb7b3d1b37c22d109340b7c2b

liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
     1 change sets check sum
          config/liquibase/changelog/20171228063150_added_entity_Student.xml::20171228063150-1::jhip
ster was: 7:1e76a424cb8d1fd8f33d27559cee9133 but is now: 7:a69d676fb7b3d1b37c22d109340b7c2b

```
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.validate(DatabaseChangeLog.java:266)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:210)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:431)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:388)

    at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java
```

:82)
        at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$0(Asyn
cSpringLiquibase.java:64)
        at io.github.jhipster.async.ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.lambda$createWrappedRunnable$
1(ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.java:66)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Thats a common problem. Fastests solution. Just Drop the database and make jhipster create it again. Liquidbase has its own tables to check consistency since you changed something its inconsistent. If this aint a production env, the fastest solution is to re-create. If its a production env. Check generated Liquidbase files checksum etc.

Hope it helps